# What is the runtime complexity of `boost::edge()` on an adjacency_list with vecS?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have an undirected `adjacency_list` graph defined as this:

```cpp
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
               boost::vecS,
               boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
               boost::no_property,
               boost::property<
                 boost::edge_weight_t, int, EdgeInfo> 
            > weighted_graph;
```

For my algorithms class, my program was too slow and only passed one of four test sets in terms of speed. I then did one small change that made my program pass all the time limit tests: I stopped using `weightmap[boost::edge(u, v, G).first]`.

Instead I looped over all edges once, and stored each edge weight twice in a 2D Vector, so that I could look it up with `weightvec[u][v]` instead.

I was not able to find any documentation on the runtime complexity of `boost::edge()`. I expected it to be constant, but it seems like that's not true. What is the complexity in terms of number of edges and vertices in the graph?

I considered if it might be due to the access to the weight property map instead, but if I still use the weightmap and store the edge descriptors, I still see that speedup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edge(v,u) searches for an edge. Why would you do this? <strike>If</strike> Since² you **know** the edges exist anyways, you should probably either:

- be using an adjacency matrix instead
- or already have a hold of the edge descriptor of the edge you knew existed (instead of searching for it)

> **Q.** I was not able to find any documentation on the runtime complexity of boost::edge().

I guess it's sort of implied by the concept of an adjacency list (see below). Also, it would be tricky to formulate due to the many generic type parameters that influence this.

> **Q.** I expected it to be constant, but it seems like that's not true.

So, let's see. An adjacency list is ... a list of adjacencies. For a graph, it it would be a list of vertices, with for each vertex a list of "adjacencies" - that is, "edges¹", represented by their target vertex (the source is already implied by the datastructure).

Finding an edge in graph `g` by (`v`,`u`) vertex endpoints requires:

- a search for (`v`) on the primary list
- search for (`u`) on the local set of adjacencies

Since you chose `vecS`/`vecS` both could be linear searches.

Luckily, because `vecS` for the vertices is random-access AND the element index is [by definition the vertex_index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:%7E:text=If%20the%20VertexList%20of%20the%20graph,range%20%5B0%2C%20num_vertices) it will be O(1). (where n is `num_vertices(g)`) and the second *O(m)* (where m is the average out-degree of vertices).

> **Q.** I considered if it might be due to the access to the weight property map instead, but if I still use the weightmap and store the edge descriptors, I still see that speedup.

Yeah, the property maps aren't doing the searching:

### CONCLUSION

There's some time to be gained, probably, by e.g. using other container selectors. However, from intuition I'm gussing you were really looking for [adjacency matrix](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_matrix.html) or even implicit graphs ([*more*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html)).

---

¹ In this case. In directed situations you would say *outgoing edges*. Boost also has a "birectionalS" representation where each list entry holds a *reundant* list of incoming edges, to optimize for some kinds of algorithms

² This can be deduced from the fact that you unconditionally use .first without checking the search result. Doing that on a non-existent edge is probably [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Gah murkdown is eating my fancy links. Trying here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:~:text=If%20the%20VertexList%20of%20the%20graph,range%20%5B0%2C%20num_vertices(g))%20and%20are%20contiguous.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. Your assumption that I *know* the edge exists is correct, We were discouraged from ever using an `adjacency matrix` in the lecture (with no reason as to why) so I'll probably not use it during the exam - but I'll read up on it nonetheless.

Comment: Btw, the reason why I knew the edge existed but did not have the descriptor was that I was working with the MST predecessor map result from prims algorithm. In retrospect, I think I should've just used the `distance_map` it computes to look up the weights of the MST edges instead.

Comment: Yup. You reached the same conclusion I would. Good luck with the exams. (By the way, Grid/Matrix mostly make sense if all/most edges exist. So, I was extrapolating from "you know this particular edge exists" to "maybe all edges exist anyways").